# Pass python variable to javascript to inform ipywidget datepicker timerange

Tags: python, datepicker, ipywidgets

I am trying to pass python variables to Javascript inorder to set the max and min dates of my ipywidget date picker. the goal is to be able to set the time range based off the max and min date of a pandas dataframe. I get an error with the code below.

code ---

````
d= DatePicker(
description='pick Date',
disabled=False
)
d.add_class('java_d')

mindate = '2022-10-01'
maxdate= '2022-10-26'

script = Javascript("
const query = '.java_d > input: first-of-type';
document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('min', {};
document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('max', {};
".format(mindate,maxdate)
)

display(d)
display(script)```



I was hoping to extract the max and min dates of my pandas dataframe and set the daterange for the datepicker.
The error I received with the above code --
Javascript error adding output!
SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
````

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue.

...

```
import json
pythondates = ['2022-10-01','2022-10-26']
script = Javascript("""
const dates = %s;
const query = '.java_d > input: first-of-type';
document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('min', dates[0];
document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('max', dates[1];
""" % json.dump(pythondates)
)
```

...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).